# Regex global variables are not being set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, activesupport

I came across something that seems unusual and I was wondering if anyone could explain why.

```
1.8.7 :001 > some_str = "Hello World"
 => "Hello World" 
1.8.7 :002 > some_str.try(:match, /^(\w*)/)
 => #<MatchData "Hello" 1:"Hello"> 
1.8.7 :003 > $1
 => nil 
1.8.7 :004 > some_str.match(/^(\w*)/)
 => #<MatchData "Hello" 1:"Hello"> 
1.8.7 :005 > $1
 => "Hello"
```

I'm not sure why the global variable `$1` is not being set the first time, but is set the second. Any insights?

Comment: You should add the rails or active-support tags to this. `try` isn't built into Ruby and it's not used commonly outside rails

Comment: `$1` is not a global variable. It is defined per thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me show you how `try` is implemented. If you want to see it yourself, then take a look at the activesupport source. It's defined in [/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb)

```
class Object
  def try(*a, &b)
    if a.empty? && block_given?
      yield self
    else
      public_send(*a, &b)
    end
  end
end
```

What this basically does, is just sending the method name and the complete arguments to the `Object`. `public_send` is the same as send, but can only be used to call public methods.

So I rewrote this, to debug your issue:

```
class Object
  def try(*a)
    result = public_send(*a)
    puts $1.inspect
    result
  end
end

string = "Hello"
string.try(:match, /^(\w*)/)
puts $1.inspect
```

This outputs

```
"Hello"
nil
```

So the great question arises: **Is this a bug in the ruby interpreter?**. *Maybe.* At least it's not documented in any official source. I found a reference that tells the following ([See *Global variables*](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/globalvars.html).)

> [...], `$_` and `$~` have local scope. Their names suggest they should be global, but they are much more useful this way, and there are historical reasons for using these names.

So it seems like `$1` is not a global variable as well, even though it is reported by the Kernel as a global variable:

```
1.9.3-p194 :001 > global_variables
 => [:$;, :$-F, :$@, :$!, :$SAFE, :$~, :$&, :$`, :$', :$+, :$=, :$KCODE, :$-K,
     :$,, :$/, :$-0, :$\, :$_, :$stdin, :$stdout, :$stderr, :$>, :$<, :$.,
     :$FILENAME, :$-i, :$*, :$?, :$$, :$:, :$-I, :$LOAD_PATH, :$",
     :$LOADED_FEATURES, :$VERBOSE, :$-v, :$-w, :$-W, :$DEBUG, :$-d, :$0,
     :$PROGRAM_NAME, :$-p, :$-l, :$-a, :$binding, :$1, :$2, :$3, :$4, :$5, :$6,
     :$7, :$8, :$9]
```

To make sure, I forwarded this incosistency to the Ruby Bug Tracker. See [Ruby Bug #6723](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6723)

Answer (score 3):

`try` is defined as

```
def try(method, *args, &block)
  send(method, *args, &block)
end
```

except of course on nil where it just returns nil. Why does this matter? Because the regexp globals aren't real globals: they're maintained on a per method and per thread basis (it's easy enough to see this by perusing the ruby source). When you call `match` via `try` the globals are set in the scope for `try` but in the next case they are set at the top level. It's easy to verify this

```
def do_match string, regexp
  string =~ regexp
  $1
end
do_match "Hello World", /^(\w*)/ #=> returns 'Hello'
$1 #=> returns nil
```

Comment: I'd recommend not using the globals except where you have to (a `sub`, `gsub`, `scan`, ... block), a `MatchData` instance offers a much better interface and even handles named capture groups.